# Adding Flag to javascript (hasClass)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have images where when you click they expand (via css). However, I also want it so that when you click, the image will be pushed to the top of the page. From what I've heard is that if I use the toggleClass function then I need to have a flag before I initiate the animation, however, I can't seem to get it to function right.

```
$("img").on("click", function (){
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");

  if ($("img").hasClass("selected")) {
    found = true;
  }


  var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.selected').offset().top - 60
            }, 100);
        }, 5);
});
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the `found` flag. What's it for?

Comment: I do not understand what are you trying to do, all the idea of using toggleClass is for stop using hasClass and flags in some cases. The toggleClass function are only adding/removing a class. Please explain yourself.

Comment: Hopefully this can clear things up: http://jsbin.com/palozuki/1/edit?html,css,output   Basically I want it so that when you press an image the body and html will shift to the top rather than just expanding at the current location.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using CSS3 transition rather than monitoring using timers. You set `transition` to transition the `top` property. Then have the `selected` class alter the `top` by toggling it. The change will cause the animation to kick in. [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/3zHH5/1/):

HTML:

```
<div class="bar">weee!</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    transition: top 1s ease 0;
    top: 100px;
}

.bar.selected{
    top : 0px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.bar').on('click',function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('selected'); 
});
```

Comment: Can I make it with css so that the html and body are the ones that move up to the image? I have a long list of images.